# How to Aggregate Mongoose.js results based on True/False Values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to get a list of totals for each field (ssl, maint, seo) based on a true/false value. I only need to know if it's true (they have hosting, or maint, or seo) to generate my totals count for each.

Host Schema:

```
var HostSchema = new Schema({
     ...
     pkg: {
         type: String,
         required: [ true, 'Hosting Package is required' ]
     },
     ssl: { type: Boolean, required: true },
     maint: { type: Boolean, required: true },
     seo: { type: Boolean, required: true },
     ...
 });
```

Here is my current code (it's unfinished):

```
// Grab all hosts with yes values for 
Hosts.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { 'ssl': true }},
        { $group: {
                'ssl': '$ssl',
                'count': {'$sum': 1}
            }
        }
    ], function(err, hosts) {
    console.log(hosts);
    console.log(err);
    if (err) console.log(err);



    // INCOMPLETE -- Waiting to see the object structure of the above results.
    var totals;
    hosts.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (item)
        totals.push({})
    });

    return res.render('./dashboard/dashboard', {
        totals: totals,
        user: req.user});
    });

});
```

Host Object:

```
{ _id: 5a1f21d5bdaeb730da394900,
  created_at: 2017-11-29T21:08:37.736Z,
  updated_at: 2017-11-29T21:08:37.736Z,
  domain: '1.com',
  pkg: 'Not Hosted',
  ssl: false,
  maint: false,
  seo: false,
  __v: 0,
  cms: [],
  ftp: [] }
```

Comment: can you post your one object so I can try to do some query in my pc?

Comment: Okay, I've edited my post to show the host object

Comment: Ohk so what you want is the total number of object that has ssl value equal to true. Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly. I need a total(true values only) for each of those. Ex. 3 ssl, 4 maint, 10 seo

Answer (score 0):

I was also able to find this. This is what I was trying to do :)

Thanks for the help!

```
Hosts.aggregate(
    [
        { $group: {
                _id: 1,
                ssl: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq:['$ssl', true]}, 1, 0]}},
                maint: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq:['$maint', true]}, 1, 0]}},
                seo: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq:['$seo', true]}, 1, 0]}},
            }
        },
    ], function(err, hosts) {
```

This returns:

```
[ { _id: 1, ssl: 3, maint: 2, seo: 2 } ]
```